# My python file is not printing to console

Tags: python

I can not seem to get this simple print to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
    def main():
        print("hello")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: How are you running it? You have to put that code in a file, then use `python filename`

Comment: Your code is indented - is that in the original? Or another thought: has the console output `sys.stdout` been reassigned?

Comment: @Barmar it should still work in IDLE shell, for example.

Comment: Have you tried `print(__name__)` ?